# vertically aligned containers unable to wrap

Tags: html, css

I have two boxes I want to be displayed side-by-side. I had them displayed side-by-side fine but the left box was not vertically centered.

I followed a guide online on how to vertically align the boxes and it worked, except now the responsiveness is all messed up, if I resize the window to be very thin, the boxes dont wrap or overflow neatly.

https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/adqLpxn5/85/

```
<div>
<style>
   #container {
     
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                flex-direction: row;
                align-items: center;
                width:100%;
            }

.box {
                width: 50%;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                margin: 5px;
                text-align: center;
}
        </style>
        <div id="container" class='w-100' >
            <!-- flex container -->

            <div class="box" style='background:red'>
                <!-- flex item -->
                <div class="form-group">
                            <div id='taggerErrDisplay'></div>
                            <input size="22" type="text" placeholder='Discogs URL' name="url" id="urlInput">
                            <button style="cursor: pointer;" id='urlInputButton' name="data" type="button"
                                onclick="submitDiscogsURL(document.getElementById('urlInput').value)">Submit</button>
                        </div>
            </div>

            <div class=" box" style='background:blue'>
                <!-- flex item -->
                <div id="drop-area">
                    <form class="my-form">
                        <h5>Upload multiple files with the file dialog or by dragging and dropping files here.</h5>
                        <br>
                        <input style="cursor: pointer;" type="file" id="file" multiple="multiple" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <style>
            #drop-area {
                /* border: 2px dashed #ccc; */
                border-radius: 20px;
                width: 480px;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            /*
            #drop-area.highlight {
            border-color: purple;
            } 
            */
            p {
                margin-top: 0;
            }

            .my-form {
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            #gallery {
                margin-top: 10px;
            }

            #gallery img {
                width: 150px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            .button {
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 10px;
                background: #ccc;
                cursor: pointer;
                border-radius: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }

            .button:hover {
                background: #ddd;
            }

            #fileElem {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
</div>
```

I tried changing the flex properties but it causes both elements to remain permanently overflowed:

[image]

Comment: don't delete and repeat the same question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/64299595/8620333)

Comment: im sorry, i thought that the private feedback duplicate message meant by question was hidden. i didnt realize until i opened this question in an incognito tab that it is still visible

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but you can try this.
Change the css as below:

```
#container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                align-items: center;
                width:100%;
            }

.box {
                width: 50%;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                margin: 5px;
                text-align: center;
```

Comment: doesnt seem to be overflowing at all with this code